# How do you update timestamp field in cassandra with C# driver?

Tags: c#, cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I am trying to update a timestamp field in Cassandra like this:

```
await new Table<MyEntity>(_session).Where(e => e.Id == entity.Id)
    .Select(u => new MyEntity
    { 
        EndDate = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow
    })
    .Update()
    .ExecuteAsync();
```

However it throws "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." with cassandra stack trace:

```
at Cassandra.Data.Linq.CqlExpressionVisitor.GetPropertyValue(MemberExpression node)
at Cassandra.Data.Linq.CqlExpressionVisitor.GetClosureValue(MemberExpression node)
at Cassandra.Data.Linq.CqlExpressionVisitor.AddProjection(Expression node, PocoColumn column)
at Cassandra.Data.Linq.CqlExpressionVisitor.FillUpdateProjection(MemberExpression node)
at Cassandra.Data.Linq.CqlExpressionVisitor.VisitMemberInit(MemberInitExpression node)
at Cassandra.Data.Linq.CqlExpressionVisitor.VisitLambda[T](Expression`1 node)
at Cassandra.Data.Linq.CqlExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression node)
at Cassandra.Data.Linq.CqlExpressionVisitor.GetUpdate(Expression expression, Object[]& values, Nullable`1 ttl, Nullable`1 timestamp, MapperFactory mapperFactory)
at Cassandra.Data.Linq.CqlUpdate.GetCql(Object[]& values)
at Cassandra.Data.Linq.CqlCommand.<ExecuteAsync>d__34.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
```

Attempting to update other fields works ok and if I remove the EndDate field from the .Select list it works so there's something I don't get.  Is there some sort of special mapping for timestamp required perhaps?

Answer (score 4):

Moments after I posted this I had a "what the hell" moment and tried this:

```
DateTimeOffset endDate = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;

 await new Table<MyEntity>(_session).Where(e => e.Id == entity.Id)
    .Select(u => new MyEntity
    { 
        EndDate = endDate
    })
    .Update()
    .ExecuteAsync();
```

Which, um. works.  So just explicitly defining the value outside the Select makes it work.  I think the Linq provider might be a bit fussy!

Answer (score 0):

[CSHARP-577](https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/CSHARP-577) fixed some issues with Properties but this question is related to a different issue which is related to static properties - [CSHARP-778](https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/CSHARP-778)

Until [CSHARP-778](https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/CSHARP-778) is released, the workaround is to do exactly what you did, i.e., use a local variable.